# Passing MSBuild Arguments to Cake Build Script to produce _PublishedWebsites

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, cakebuild

I am currentlly in the process of writing a Cake build script to build a number of ASP.NET MVC sites.

At the moment I am unable to see an option to pass arguments to MSBuild to produce the _PublishedWebsites folder for deployment.

I believe the arguments that I need to pass are:

```
/p:OutDir=$(build.stagingDirectory)
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
```

If there is an alternative approach which produces the same output content just not in the same folder directory that would be fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following example should set the correct MSBuild properties when building your website solution from Cake.

```
MSBuild("./src/Website.sln", new MSBuildSettings()
  .WithProperty("OutDir", "$(build.stagingDirectory)")
  .WithProperty("DeployOnBuild", "true")
  .WithProperty("WebPublishMethod", "Package")
  .WithProperty("PackageAsSingleFile", "true")
  .WithProperty("SkipInvalidConfigurations", "true"));
```

To set the output directory of the website, simply swap out the `"$(build.stagingDirectory)"` part with the path to the directory where you want the output to appear.

You can read more about the MSBuild alias in Cake here: http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.msbuild/

Comment: What version of Cake are you using? I am getting errors for `DeployOnBuild`, `WebPublishMethod`, `PackageAsSingleFile` not existing on `MSBuildSettings`. The documentation linked above also does not list these properties.

Comment: They are not properties on `MSBuildSettings`, they are MSBuild properties.

Comment: I thought `WithProperty` was just a fluent way of setting properties on the starting object. Like `x.WithProperty("y", 1)` would be the same as `x.y = 1`

Answer (score 1):

For FileSystem publish it can be done this way:

```
MSBuild(/**project path**/, settings =>
    settings.SetConfiguration(/**configuration**/)
    .WithProperty("DeployTarget", "WebPublish")
    .WithProperty("DeployOnBuild", /**boolean**/)
    .WithProperty("PackageAsSingleFile", /**boolean**/)
    .WithProperty("WebPublishMethod", "FileSystem")
    .WithProperty("PublishUrl", /**url**/)
);
```

Comment: Configuration is?

Comment: What version of Cake are you using? I am getting errors for `DeployOnBuild`, `DeployTarget`, `WebPublishMethod`, `PackageAsSingleFile` not existing on `MSBuildSettings`. The documentation also does not list these properties.